Power Bi How to have card visual say "Multiple" if Multiple values are selected
In power bi I have a card visual that only displays the first/top value if multiple values are selected.
Ex:
Card Visual
Using only the CARD visual how can I have the card instead display "Multiple" or similar if more than one value is selected?
I'm not interested in using any other visual as an alternative, just the card visual.

I would count the number of distinct records in a field and if only 1 use that value otherwise multiple.
DistinctRecordCheck = 
VAR DistinctCount = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Field])
RETURN 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        DistinctCount = 0, "null",
        DistinctCount = 1, SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Field]),
        DistinctCount > 1, "multiple"
    )


This worked perfectly. Marking as solution. Thank you.
